# What is the use of "*&" in the code below

Tags: c

What is the use of `*&` in the `printf` statement and how is the output `R`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char* str = "ReplyCodeChallenge";
    printf("%c\n", *&*str);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is: R

Comment: It reminds me my college days, it seems like assignment question.

Comment: Ridiculous obfuscation.

Comment: It's useless. `*&*str` is the same as `*str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a matter of multiple referencing and dereferencing.

`str` is a string pointer

`*str` is equivalent to `*(str + 0)` which is the same as `str[0]`

`&(*str)` denotes the address of `str[0]`

`*(&*str)` simply dereferences that address and gives `str[0]` back to you

The brackets don't matter here because both `&` and `*` fall under the same precedence group and their associativity is from right to left.

Since `str[0]` is *'R'*, that's your output.

By this example, you can conclude that `*&` or (`*&*&`...) makes no significant difference. But not always, you may see that syntax used in function headers to receive an argument of pointer-type through pass-by-reference mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

`char* str = "ReplyCodeChallenge";` defines `str` to be a pointer to `char` and initializes it to point to the first character of `"ReplyCodeChallenge"`. (`"ReplyCodeChallenge"` is a string literal, which is effectively an array. In this use, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, and that pointer is used as the initial value for `str`.)

`str` is a pointer to `char`, which points to the `'R'`.

`*str` is that `char`, because `*` gives the thing that a pointer (an address) points to.

`&*str` is the address of that `char`, because `&` gives the address (a pointer) of a thing.

`*&*str` is that `char`, again because `*` gives the thing that a pointer points to.

Answer (score 1):

There are already enough good answers but I add also mine --  like in any expression, you first of all need to split it in parsing tree, in order to detect the order of evaluation of subexpressions.

> *&*str

Here you have 3 applications of 2 unary operators, each of them is 
prefix unary-operator.  So they have the same precedence, so the parsing tree is like that

> (*(&(*str)))

The first application `*(str)` will return the first character from the beginning of `str`, which has the same address as `str` itself. So, `&*str` will be the address of `str`.  So your applications will reduce to

> *str

which is the 1st character (integer that represents the ASCII code) from string.

Answer (score 0):

`*` - dereferences the object referenced by the pointer
`&` - gets reference to the object

`char *p = "ABCD;` - `&*p`, `&*&*p`, `&*&*&*p`, `&*&*&*p`... - does nothing, it is still reference stored in the pointer.

`*&*p`, `*&*&*p`, `*&*&*&*p`, `*&*&*&*p`... - just dereferences the `char` referenced by the pointer `p`, in this case `'A'`

https://godbolt.org/z/ijffmP

Comment: Maybe you can clarify your last statement, I think I know the thing you are getting at, but it doesn’t have much to do with arrays, they have addresses, those addresses can be dereferenced, the elements have addresses that can be dereferenced. An array element that is a pointer can be dereferenced, so a big bold ‘It does not apply to the arrays’ is worded funny.

Comment: @GradyPlayer you comment something which does not exists anymore